# Subgroups of $S_8$ Isomorphic to Other Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Why does $S_8$ contain subgroups isomorphic to $Z_{15}$, U(16), and $D_8$?

Comment: What is $U(16)$?

Comment: U(16) is the set of all positive integers less than 16 and relatively prime to 16 (the group operation is multiplication modulo n)

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? Are you asking what the subgroups are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By $\mathbb Z_{15}$ I assume you mean a cyclic group of order $15$.  To see that this is a subgroup of a group you just have to find an element of order $15$ in that group, for example $(1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5)(6 \ 7 \ 8)$.

For $U(16)$ there are $8$ elements of that group, so in this case Cayley's theorem does give you that $U(16)$ is a subgroup of $S_8$.  Let multiplication by an element of $U(16)$ permutes the $8$ elements of $U(16)$ so the subgroup of $S_8$ is the subgroup of all the permutations you get on the elements of $U(16)$ by left multiplying by an element of $U(16)$.

For $D_8$ I assume you mean symmetries of a regular $8$-gon.  The $8$ vertices of the $8$-gon are permuted by the elements of $D_8$, so you take these permutations as the subgroup.

Comment: Thank you very much! That clears this up for me.